# How to add margin in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-16">
  <div class="item col-xs-8"></div>
  <div class="item col-xs-8"></div>
  <div class="item col-xs-8"></div>
</div>
```

Blocks with `col-xs-8` have CSS `display:inline-block`. How can I add `margin` for each `col-xs-8`? I tried, but element are moved from inline to next line.

Comment: Could you provide a js fiddle or codepen and desired outcome? I can help further then.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want little space b/w elements you can use padding Because margin Will Add Space around elements so if your `col-xs-8` have like `50% width` then in row you have `50% xs-8 block + margin space + 50% xs-8 block` so your element will moved to next line.